# clone first div and append after next div using class name

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, image

I am having structure like:-

```html
<div class="container">
    <h1 class="header-div">Title 1</h1>
    <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.</p>
    <div class="image-div">image1</div>
</div>
<div class="container">
    <h1 class="header-div">Title 2</h1>
    <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.</p>
    <div class="image-div">image2</div>
</div>
<div class="container">
    <h1 class="header-div">Title 3</h1>
    <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.</p>
    <div class="image-div">image3</div>
</div>
```

---

I want to take **h1** and append it after **.image-div** and want to do it for every block

Comment: Have you any code to show? Have you tried anything?

Comment: $(".header-div").clone().appendTo(".image-div"); was trying this. But problem using class name. and I have only option to use class name selectors

Comment: @Yogi what is the output of your code?

Comment: Title 1

Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.

image1
Title 1

Title 2

Title 3

Title 2

Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.

image2
Title 1

Title 2

Title 3

Title 3

Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.

image3
Title 1

Title 2

Title 3

Answer (score 0):

Two things

- `appendTo` will append **inside** `div` **not after** `div`.
- without iteration it will clone all of them together and append all these clones for every `image-div`

You need to try

```
$(".header-div").each( function(){
  $(this).clone().insertAfter( $(this).parent().find( ".image-div" ) );
});
```

or

```
$(".header-div").each( function(){
  $(this).clone().appendTo( $(this).parent() );
});
```

Comment: Thanks so much @guruvinder372
First one works perfect for me :)

Answer (score 0):

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Lqtf8nor/1/)

It could be done like so

```
var container = $(".container");
$.each(container, function(k, e){
    $(e).find('.header-div').clone().appendTo($(e).find(".image-div"))
} )
```

`each` loops through array of main div elements where image and title divs are, and just move title to another DOM position.

Comment: Thanks @Mantas.. but I wanted to append after .image-div...
Its adding h1 div inside .image-div.

But this will also work if I make it like
var container = $(".container");
$.each(container, function(k, e){
    $(e).find('.header-div').clone().appendTo($(this))
} )